# Loading JSON string into a pie chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, java, json, charts, highcharts

I need to include my json String output to a highcharts --pie chart category
but chart is not loading properly

This is my JSON string

```
var json = {"{\"name\":\"BillToMobile\"}":{"y":2.35},"{\"name\":\"Telenav\"}":{"y":13.59}}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: json
    }]
});
```

Below is the chart what I'm getting when loading this jsonstring.
Can any one help me with this because I'm new to this.Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the chart error output]

Comment: Your JSON is valid, but it doesn't hold the values you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try formatting your json this way

```
var json = [{name: "BillToMobile", y: 2.35}, {name: "Telenav", y: 13.59}]
```

To convert the json you have you can use this:

**ES5 or earlier**

```
var properJson = [];
for (var i in json) {
   var item = JSON.parse(i);
   for (var j in json[i]) {
      item[j] = json[i][j];
   }
   properJson.push(item);
}
```

**ES6**

```
var properJson = [];
for (var i in json) {
   var item = JSON.parse(i);
   Object.assign(item, json[i]);
   properJson.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I format this inside the javascript ? Is there any method or hint ?

Comment: Thanks a lot . I'm really happy with your quick response. It's working fine now